# How to set screensaver on/off and set custom screensaver in tizen web application for Samsung Smart TV?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

For setting screensaver on/off we are using following API from [AppCommon API](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/guides/fundamentals/setting-screensaver.html)

```
webapis.appcommon.setScreenSaver(
  webapis.appcommon.AppCommonScreenSaverState.SCREEN_SAVER_ON,
  function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
);

webapis.appcommon.setScreenSaver(
  webapis.appcommon.AppCommonScreenSaverState.SCREEN_SAVER_OFF,
  function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
);
```

Are there any API methods to set the time after which the screensaver will start, like getting screensaver time and setting the screensaver time through a web application?

> Note:
> If "Auto Protection Time" is switched off in the TV settings, enabling
> and disabling the screensaver using the AppCommon API has no effect.
> To be published on Samsung Apps TV, your application must enable and
> disable the screensaver appropriately.

Using the above API method screensaver on/off success blocked called successfully but what does the note above about "Auto Protection Time" and how to handle that case.

Also, are there any API/Methods to set custom screensaver?

Answer (score 2):

The objective of Screensaver is prevent having a static image on the screen during long periods and avoid burn-in effects in some screens. You can find two situations:

A) Auto protection ebabled: In this case your app is in charge of managing the screen saver. For example if you have a streaming app like Netflix Samsung does't want the screen saver appears while a customer is watching a film, so in situations like play, pause, stop, etc. you must your methods

In general terms, every time your app starts playing a video, your must disable the screen saver. And when a static picture comes, you must enable the screen saver (i.e. in pause, stop, exit events). All of these are also applied if your app is a video game.

B) Auto protection has been disabled by the user: In this case your method to enabling or disabling the screen saver will have no effect due it will never appears

Regarding using a custom screen saver, sorry but I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

Tizen for TVs doesn't support any custom screen savers at this point. Samsung has however hinted at custom Ambient applications, which is their name for screen savers, but haven't seen any news about this for a long time